# New stochastic calculus

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus, random-walk, stopping-times

I am interested in Kagi and Renko approach and hope I can use it for a random walk process. I searched for it on internet but I couldnt find any basic material to read about it. Can someone please recommend me some basic reading for Kagi and Renko stopping time construction?

Many thanks.